# I won't be able to reward this bounty, can I have it extended?

Tags: support

I put [this bounty](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67433/identify-this-young-adult-childrens-book-with-a-strong-and-clever-female-protago) up on my question hoping to generate interest and an answer where it has proven difficult to find.

I forgot, when I posted this bounty, that I was going to be out of town for a week starting tomorrow, and therefore the bounty would expire, possibly while the question has been answered, but without being able to reward that bounty.

I'd like to request, if possible, that this bounty be extended so that I can reward a correct answer when I return on the 21st (EST).

Comment: You can access StackExchange on mobile (web site or dedicated app)

Comment: @DVK Good advice, but I won't be able to access any internet-capable device on this trip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I don't usually offer to do this, but I can cancel the bounty.  I think that'll refund the reputation you put up for it.  When you're back, you can place a fresh bounty.

Note that usually, a second (or third, fourth, etc) bounty on a post is required to be larger than the previous one, and I don't know if that will apply here.  Something to be aware of.

Comment: I'll gladly make it a larger bounty.  My only concern is not being able to award the bounty to the correct answer, since I will have no access to any internet-capable device while on this trip.

Comment: @Zibbobz SHAZAM!

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested in knowing the answer too. It does seem vaguely familiar although a quick Google hasn't revealed any obvious candidates.

I'd be quite happy if you want me to place the bounty (out of my own rep, obviously) and reward the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you, but I think I'll take up Keen's offer.  I'd really like to reward a good answer, and I am not afraid to make it a little higher. :)